# Java: Shift all character-codes inside a String by a constant value

Tags: java, arrays, string, shift, character-codes

This works:

```java
for (char c : sourceString.toCharArray()) 
    destString += (char) (c + shiftValue);

System.out.println(destString);
```

Is there a better/faster (optimized) way?

Comment: Since your code is working, this would actually fit better over at **[codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well I'd [avoid using repeated string concatenation](http://jonskeet.uk/java/strings.html), to start with. That's a very well known performance problem.

In this case, you know the exact length you need to start with, so you don't even need a `StringBuilder` - a `char[]` is fine:

```
char[] result = new char[srcString.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = (char) (srcString.charAt(i) + shiftValue);
}
String destString = new String(result);
```

(The [answer using `toCharArray`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40969215/22656) and then overwriting each element is nice too, although I'd expect any performance differences to be small. You'd want to test it with your actual system if this is *really* performance-critical code. The main point is that both are O(N) approaches rather than O(N<sup>2</sup>).)

However, you should think about whether you *really* want to just shift - most exercises like this are more *rotate* than shift, e.g. if you start with A-Z, you should end up with A-Z as well... a shift value of 1 should change Z to A, not to "the Unicode character after Z" (which is `[`). That *may* not be a requirement in your case, but you should certainly consider it.

Answer (score 7):

A shorter version. No need to call `charAt(i)` every time in the loop.

```
char[] result = srcString.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i] += shiftValue;
}
String destString = new String(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is:

```
StringBuilder destString = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : srcString.toCharArray()) {
    destString.appned((char) (c + shiftValue));
}
System.out.println(destString.toString());
```